# Write to user specified file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, compiler-errors

Can I specify what file I want to write into in C++? I want to be able to type in the filename and write into that file. When I try making `myfile.open("example.txt")` `myfile.open(var)`, I get a big error...

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream >::open(std::string&)’
>       /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:650: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]

Can you make any sense of this or explain what I am doing wrong? I have a feeling this is very simple, as this is my first week using C++.

Comment: In general you want to post the smallest working example of your problem, otherwise people are left guessing at the details.  Help people help you.

Comment: @luke I did, that was the `myfile.open("example.txt")`.

Comment: that doesn't tell us what `myfile` is declared as, nor is it the line that produces the error.  Think of it this way:  you want to show us the shortest version of your program that demonstrates the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `var` is an [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), try:

```
myfile.open(var.c_str());
```

The error tells you exactly what's wrong, although the precision of the template types named doesn't help make that crystal clear.  Take a look at the reference for [.open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/).  It takes a `const char *` for the filename, and another optional mode parameter.  What you are passing is not a `const char *`.

Comment: I get an `error: ‘struct std::string’ has no member named ‘c_string’`

Comment: You want .c_str(), not .c_string().

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. I must just automatically read str as string. :D

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, it is trying to match the parameters with a character pointer and std::string is not a character pointer.  However std::string::c_str() will return one.

try:

```
myfile.open(var.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes you can specify a file to open and write into many different ways.
If you're using an fstream and want to write plain text out, this is one way:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
  std::string filename = "myfile.txt";
  std::fstream outfile;
  outfile.open( filename.c_str(), std::ios::out );
  outfile << "writing text out.\n";
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `var` a `std::string`? If so, you should be passing `var.c_str()` as there is not a variant of `.open()` that takes a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable a `string`, `char[]`, or `char*`?  I think the open() method wants a c-style string, which would be `char[]` or `char*`, so you'd need to call the `.c_str()` method on your string when you pass it in:

```
myfile.open(var.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a second parameter to the open call. it should be like myfile.open("example.txt", fstream::out)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. It says: the `basic_ofstream` class (your file object) does not have a member function that's called "open" and takes a single argument of type `string` (your `var`). You need to go from `string` to `const char *` - for that, you use `var.c_str()`.